# void ** equivalent to void * return?

Tags: c++, c

```
    void * alligned_malloc(size_t bytes , uint16_t allign)
{

    uint16_t offset = allign - 1 + sizeof(void*);

    void* p1 = malloc(offset + bytes);
    void**p2 = (void**)(((size_t)p1+offset) & ~(allign - 1));
    p2[-1] = p1;

    return p2; // Why is this correct ? should not the return be p2[0] as it is     returning void**

}
```

Please help me understand this modified malloc how is void** equivalent to void * return in this code ?

Comment: Just check `printf("%d =? %d\d", sizeof(some_ptr_to_ptr), sizeof(*some_ptr_to_ptr));` which amounts to `sizeof(void **)` and `sizeof(void *)`

Comment: As `void*` & friends are for danger seekers. You really should know what you are doing if using pointers to pointers to ... `void`. Due to implicit type conversions here, you lose the luxery of the compiler's type checking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any kind of pointer can be implicitly converted to a `void *`, including a pointer to a `void *`, aka `void **`.

Comment: Thanks everyone so much , I understand now implicit conversions really obfuscate clear code

Answer (score 5):

A `void*` can be pointing to *anything*, including another pointer.

Comment: Or rather, the reason why there is no compiler error is because `void*` can be converted to any other pointer type without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 3):

> how is `void**` equivalent to `void *` return in this code ?

Any pointer type can be converted to `void*`.

> should not the return be p2[0] as it is     returning void**

No. `p2` is the address of the aligned memory, so that is what the function should return. Within the function, it's reinterpreted as `void**` in order to store the original address before the aligned memory; presumably, this is read back by the corresponding function that frees the memory. Outside the function, it's not interpreted as pointing to any particular type - it's up to the caller to decide what to use the aligned memory for.

Answer (score 2):

You can return it. But I doubt that it works as intended.

At least, you cannot simply `free()` it; you have to have a separate function for that.

Then, however, it will work.